# Add/Remove Class on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sorry if the question title isn't specific enough... but I really have no idea about the name of the feature I'm aiming here...

Here is the basic stuff at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Leader/f7fg9t6e/)

```
<style>
body { margin: 0; text-align: center; }
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; display: flex; }
li { flex: 1; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; background: #fff; }
.current { background-color: #eee; }
#content { margin-top: 50px; }
#content > div { padding: 500px 15px; }
#content > div + div { border-top: 1px solid black; }
</style>

<ul id="nav">
  <li id="nav-1" class="current">No.1</li>
  <li id="nav-2">No.2</li>
  <li id="nav-3">No.3</li>
  <li id="nav-4">No.4</li>
  <li id="nav-5">No.5</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
  <div id="content-1">#01: “First Chapter”</div>
  <div id="content-2">#02: “Second Chapter”</div>
  <div id="content-3">#03: “Third Chapter”</div>
  <div id="content-4">#04: “Fourth Chapter”</div>
  <div id="content-5">#05: “Fifth Chapter”</div>
</div>
```

- When the top of the viewport haven't passed #content-2, #nav-1 would have the 'current' class.
- When the viewport passed #content-2, #nav-1 would lose the 'current' class and #nav-2 would get the 'current' class.
- and so on.

Some of the sites which I've seen using such feature are all using specific scripts, where one would need to made minor changes to the javascript when the number on objects in the content/nav changed.

I'm hoping to know a script where it could handle dynamic number of objects in the content/nav.

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Thank You.

Comment: will [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/) help you?

Comment: A good example... but I'm wondering if we refresh the page while the viewport is in the middle of the document, we could retain whichever <a> that should have the 'active' class. The example you're giving will reset the position of 'active' class when the page is refreshed... and will work properly again once the user scrolled the page. (I'm sorry if I'm being too picky here...)

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for :

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(e){    
        for (var i = 1; i < $('#nav li').length; i++) {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#content-'+i).position().top){
                $('#nav li').removeClass('current');
                $('#nav-'+i).addClass('current');
            } 
        };        
    })   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7fg9t6e/1/

Do not forget to add jQuery to your project ;)

Comment: Simple and easy to understand... a bit modification need to be made to make it properly work for the LAST content. But a bit know-how on CSS selector should suffice to fill the gap :D

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to +1 and accept the answer bro' ! :)